# Why is hash function fast?

Tags: hash, hashtable

Let's say I created a database that stores just name and password.
Then if I use a hash function(let's say md5) to one-way encrypt the password which the user enters when signing up.

Name = "James"
Password = "password1234" -> "bdc87b9c894da5168059e00ebffb9077"
The encrypted message will be stored in the database with his name "James"

Now when he enters his password to login, his password's md5 hash will be compared with the encrpyted message in the database.
So, if there is 1 million data on my database, the server will need to search through all the data to find "bdc87b9c894da5168059e00ebffb9077".

How come is it possible to locate the password's position instantly?

Comment: What books did  you read about databases and algorithms? Start with [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) then look inside the source code of open source database systems (like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) and many others)

Comment: The server doesn't search the DB by password. It first finds the user (by username or email) and then compares the given password with what is stored.

Comment: Hash functions are used for a variety of different purposes. They can be used to index data in a database, but they can also be used to protect passwords stored in that database. BTW, MD5 is a horribly bad choice to protect passwords; you want a hash designed specifically for that task, like Argon2, scrypt, bcrypt, or possibly PBKDF2 (although I wouldn't recommend that one).

Comment: (Actually, MD5 isn't really suitable for anything anymore -- it's not secure enough for cryptographic purposes, and it's not as fast as others for non-cryptographic purposes. And it was *never* suitable for password hashing. So just don't use it.)